# error when I included PCL passthrough filter

Tags: ros, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am using `iai_kinect` to use Kinect 2.0 under Ubuntu OS. I wanted to use the passthrough filter for point cloud. And always show the error of segmentation fault (core dumped).

And then I found out that even I just added `#include <pcl/filters/passthrough.h>` in the beginning, the program doesn't work anymore. The error message shows `The program has unexpectedly finished.` When I deleted this line, it just works.

I have no idea, why it doesn't work by just including a header file in the cpp. Does anyone have an idea.

Best regards
ZYJ

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210066/error-when-i-included-pcl-passthrough-filter/) by [ZYJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/22572/zyj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-05-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ritwik1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/20200/ritwik1993/) on 2015-06-25**:
We need more information! What functions are you trying to implement? What is your application?
Generally speaking, I use nodelets wherever I can to implement PCL filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem by myself later on. The reason is that PCL does not support c++11 orginally. In my code, some c++11 functionalities are used. So I build the code from the their github repositary, and add SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11") to the CMakeList.txt. Then make and make install the PCL libaray. Then it will solve the problem.

---

Originally posted by [ZYJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/22572/zyj/) with karma: 21 on 2015-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-06-26**:
How can it be PCL does not support C++11? C++11 is 100% compatible with previous C++ standards, so everything compiling under C++0x should compile under C++11. Am I wrong?

**Comment by [ZYJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/22572/zyj/) on 2015-06-26**:
hey here is the link http://www.pcl-developers.org/Safe-to-use-C-11-features-td5709234.html